# Installing an old version of SSM on Windows Server 2008 EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ssm

I am trying to install and old version of SSM on a Windows 2008 R2 EC2 instance that I have migrated using AWS Application Migration Service. The last compatible version is apparently version 2.3.1644.0 according to this source: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ssm-agent-windows-ec2/.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Is there a user data script that I could use?

Also the servers I am migrating is in a test VSphere environment and are in the 'Test in progress' stage on AWS Application Migration Service.

Using a user data script I found here:  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ssm-agent-windows-ec2/. Did not seem to install ssm and the script is also for the latest version... I need an older version of SSM

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access that version of the SSMAgent using this URL: [AmazonSSMAgentSetup v2.3.1644.0](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/2.3.1644.0/windows_386/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe)
If you replace the URL in the Userdata script from the page you reference with the version-specific link your Userdata script should work.
i.e.

```
(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads-windows/SSMAgent/2.3.1644.0/windows_386/AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe", $dir + "\AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe")
Start-Process .\AmazonSSMAgentSetup.exe -ArgumentList @("/q", "/log", "install.log") -Wait
```